# Reading a text input in kivy

Tags: python, kivy

Hi all I'm currently working on a project. It's a chess game that requires a login page to start. Currently, I've got the login page working and formatted to a point where I'm happy however I'm struggling to read what the user has inputted for their username and password due to kivys system.

````
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.core.window import Window
#inport all kivy dependencies without install entire package

def callback(instance):
    print('The button is pressed')
def readUserInfo(instance):
    print(MyGrid..name.text)

class MyGrid(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        Window.size = (300, 120)
        super(MyGrid, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 2
        self.row_force_default=True,
        self.row_default_height=80


        self.add_widget(Label(text="Username: ", size_hint_x=None, width=300))
        self.name = TextInput(multiline=False, size_hint_x=None, width=300, font_size = 50)
        self.add_widget(self.name)

        self.add_widget(Label(text="Password: ", size_hint_x=None, width=300))
        self.lastName = TextInput(multiline=False, password = True, size_hint_x=None, width=300, font_size = 50)
        self.add_widget(self.lastName)

        self.add_widget(Button(text='Register', on_press=callback, size_hint_x=None, width=300, background_color =(99,180,207, 0.8)))
        self.add_widget(Button(text='Login', on_press=readUserInfo , size_hint_x=None, width=300))



class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyGrid()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()```
````

Answer (score 0):

You can get the input of the user in the TextInput by accessing its `text` property.

For instance `self.name = TextInput(multiline=False, size_hint_x=None, width=300, font_size = 50)`

You can get the user input to that `TextInput` by calling `self.name.text`